# Opening a .nc file in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I am new to R Programming and am having difficulty getting a .nc file into R. I have read about 'ncdf' and 'netCDF' packages which can do this but they appear not to be recognised by R anymore. Now, I am completely lost as to what do do next. Is there a package that can do this?

The file is: shum_daily_2010-2010.nc and it is climate data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open `nc` files with the [`raster`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/index.html) package:

```
library("raster")
r = raster("data/nc_3B42.20060101.03.7A.HDF.Z.ncml.nc")
```

which can be installed in the usual way

```
install.packages("raster")
```

Comment: Except if the NetCDF file is a "station" file. It will fail.

Comment: This will only open the first layer within the whole *.nc file, right?

Comment: Using the raster() function from the {raster} package will only open the first layer of the *.nc file, but you can use the stack() or brick() functions from the {raster} package to read all the layers at once, too.